# How can I get Ubuntu 16.04 onto a USB flash drive USB

Tags: usb, downloads

Can anyone give me step by step instructions on how to get Ubuntu 16.04 LTS onto a memory stick please?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the size of the usb stick you are gonna use. You only need 8GB so a larger one could be partitioned to reserve space for data

Install Ubuntu program : unetbootin

Download the iso from [the Ubuntu site](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) or use the internet option in unetbootin program (not tried)

start unetbootin and make your usb stick, pointing to your downloaded iso or via internet

To boot from the USB, change BIOS to boot USB first or hit the key to access the boot menu

You made need to use Gparted to set the boot flag

Answer (score 0):

1.For making a usb stick, you can follow the instructions from the link below
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu
2.For installation process, refer to the below link
https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop